# HTML5 Geolocation not prompting for location on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to get Safari to prompt me for my location with a very simple code. I'm working on a **remote** Macbook mini from my PC running Ubuntu. Inside the Macbook environment, the code below works on Firefox and Chrome perfectly fine. But on Safari nothing happens, I don't get prompt or nothing. I wish I received any errors in the console but the function does not even fire at all. Nothing happens. Nada. Anyone has ever faced a problem like this?

If I go and try it here on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) same thing happen, meaning I click on Try it and nothing happens. But it works fine in all other browsers.

code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should set an error callback as well and see what you get.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: @Brad: Hey Brad okay now I see this : code: 1
message: User denied Geolocation... Thats bizzarre because they didn't even ask in the first place?

Comment: Was the user *ever* asked?  Alternatively, the browser is configured to reject these requests, or maybe doesn't even support them on this device in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by handling errors. Safari and ios seem to require error handling to work.

This works :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working

Answer (score 2):

Go to Finder -> Apple -> System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy then add Safari to the whitelist. Try if that works.

Or

In Safari select Safari > Preferences. Click the Privacy icon in the Preferences window. Unselect the "Deny without prompting" option.